# Float not working (anymore) in Outlook for Mac?

Tags: macos, outlook, signature

I want to use float in a signature to achieve a responsive column-layout.

According to several sources, like this one:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/positioning-display/float/

float is supported in Outlook for Mac. However, when using a very simple block of code as a signature in Outlook for Mac, the floats don't seem to work.

I used the following signature:

```
<body>
    <div style="float: left; width: 100px;">
        1
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 100px;">
        2
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%; clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
```

Where the 1 and 2 should come next to each other, which in Outlook for Mac they do not. Am I missing something here or are the sources telling me that float is supported by Outlook for Mac incorrect?

Comment: Are you testing the signature before or after send?

Comment: @Digital_Frankenstein: in the preview as well as before send. Edit: just tested after sending as well to be sure, but no difference.

Comment: Okay, I would have been surprised if it worked in the signature preview as well, so I wanted to see if it was working before send. Signatures have less support for CSS than email templates. They're essentially stripped by most email clients when placed into the email client signature area. This is to ensure the most basic HTML is used and holds, no matter where it is sent. I would simplify your layout and use tables to ensure the most basic form of HTML is used.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback! I've changed it to tables and that works fine (also in preview). So I guess I can only use that page I referenced for e-mail templates and the signature on the receiving end.